# snapshot resolutions for Aforge Snapshot Maker

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, snapshot, aforge, logitech

I simply want to apply the [Aforge Snapshot Maker example](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html)  , I have a Logitech HD C525 camera, The video resolutions is listed but the snapshot resolutions have only one item : **Not Supported**

May i know why it's not supported?

Is there any way to get it work?

Comment: I have found this [link](http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2781) , Exactly have the same problem, but no solution, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most of the new cameras are not supported yet, I have used a simple solution get a snapshot ,

```
Bitmap img = videoSourcePlayer.GetCurrentVideoFrame();
```

Comment: what is videoSourcePlayer?

Comment: @MatiullahKarimi it is the control from the `AForge.Controls` namespace